# Can duct be moved?

Tags: hvac

[image]Making doorway deom kitchen to dining  room. Found this in way. We need wall to go just left of center of duct. Can we cut top and put in cap with center hole and use flex pipe to connect to floor? There will be header to where you see the change In paint color.

Comment: Whats the duct for, what are its dimensions. where do teh two ends go ?